# Can we run/test desktop applications on browserStack?

Tags: testing, cross-browser, browserstack

Can anyone let me know whether we will be able to run/test desktop applications on BrowserStack?
I'm exploring options to test one of the desktop applications on multiple operating systems and devices.

Answer (score 1):

BrowserStack currently does not support testing of Desktop Applications. It only supports browser based testing and mobile application testing (iOS/Android)

Comment: Thank you so much,Anthony! For Android tab, can we install any application from play store and test ?